# Value not showing in the table

Tags: html, typescript, next.js, react-props

I am trying to populate the table using the data received in the props, by looping over it. But data is not rendering in the UI :(, if I manually put any data it is showing. Following is my code

**Code To populate**

```
{props.uiProductCart.forEach((data) => {
           
            <tr data-index={data.srno}>
              <td>{data.srno}</td>
              <td>{data.name}</td>
              <td>{data.price}</td>
              <td>{data.quantity}</td>
              <td>{data.total}</td>
              <td>
                <BtnDelete title="Remove" />
              </td>
            </tr>;
          })}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having the full code sample, it's hard to be sure that my answer will be complete.
However, as a start I believe the `forEach` in the first line should be a `map` instead.

`forEach`

> The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once for each array element.

*Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach*

`map`

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

*Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map*

In other words, the `forEach` function doesn't return anything to be rendered by react. It's simply looping over a collection, constructing your template and then discarding it.
While a `map` function would return the constructed template to react, to be rendered.

This is also demonstrated/documented in the official React documentation here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

### Example

I've set up a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-grass-4i68m?file=/src/App.js:222-258) as an example.

### Note: Brackets!

Make sure to use the correct brackets when replacing the `forEach` by the `map`.

Both of the following will work, as the map function isn't returning anything:

```
{props.uiProductCart.map((data) => {
  return (
    <tr data-index={data.srno}>
      ...
    </tr>
  );
})}
```

```
{props.uiProductCart.map((data) => (
  <tr data-index={data.srno}>
    ...
  </tr>
))}
```

But this will **NOT** work:

```
{props.uiProductCart.map((data) => {
    <tr data-index={data.srno}>
      ...
    </tr>
})}
```

Comment: Thanx for ur precious time bro....bt it didn't work. I have already tried it.

Comment: @SumitSingh I've expanded on my answer by adding a code-sandbox example and a notice about brackets. Can you check if this resolves your issue?

Comment: Thnx mate it is resolved my problem